# how to create the pagination for customized portfolio template

Tags: 7, paging

I will create the portfolio gallery page using custom content types with thumbnail and bigimage  image fields. then i am using the following code for rendering content types

```
<?php 
$content_type = 'websiteportfolio';
$query = new EntityFieldQuery();

$entities = $query->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node')
->entityCondition('bundle', $content_type)
->propertyCondition('status', 1)
->pager(9)
->execute();
$nodes = entity_load('node', array_keys($entities['node']));?>


<?php
  $i = 1;
  foreach($nodes as $val=>$key1)

  {

 ?>


 <div class="thumbnail-box">
<a href=<?='sites/default/files/'. $key1->field_bigimage['und']['0']['filename']; ?> rel="lightbox[portfolio]"  title="<?= 'Portfolio'.$i ?>"><img src=<?='sites/default/files/websiteportfolio/'. $key1->field_images['und']['0']['filename']; ?> alt="<?= 'Portfolio'.$i ?>" /></a>

</div>

 <?php 
$i++;
}


 ?>
```

finally i got the 9  thumbnail images in my page and also light box functionality working well.My issue Only show first 9 images I need pagination for showing the remaining images how  can fix this issue..

Answer (score 1):

First things first, that code shouldn't be in the template file; it should be in a preprocess function. The reasons for this have been documented at great length both on this site and the internet in general so I won't go into them here.

You might also find the [`l()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/l/7) function interesting, as well as [`theme_image()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!theme.inc/function/theme_image/7)...API replacements for the custom HTML you're building up.

Other than that, the only thing you're missing is the code to actually render the pager; that would entail adding this to your preprocess function, after the query has been run:

```
$vars['pager'] = theme('pager');
```

And in the template file simply outputting it wherever you'd like it:

```
<?php echo $pager; ?>
```